# SQL distinct multiple columns

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table as following:

```
book_id   author_id     mark     year
   1          1          BAD     2014
   1          1         MEDIUM   2014
   1          1         GREAT    2015
```

I would like to execute a query that will give me the best book for each author.
Something like this:

```
book_id   author_id     mark     year
   1          1         GREAT    2015
```

I tried to use the distinct keyword on multiple fields - but when I do this:

```
select distinct book_id, author_id from Books
```

I get only the book_id and the author_id (as expected) - but I also need the mark and the year - but I cannot add it to the distinct phrase.

Currently I'm using Postgres 9.4 but I need an ANSI-SQL solution.

Is there a way I can do that?

Comment: If a book has several rows, how to chose mark and year, i.e. the row to return? (Best mark, or latest year? What if two rows with same mark but different year, or same year but different mark...)

Comment: In this case we'll need the best mark

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[greatest-n-per-group](/questions/tagged/greatest-n-per-group) questions are usually solved using window functions:

```
select *
from (
   select book_id, author_id, mark, year, 
          row_number() over (partition by author_id order by case mark when 'GREAT' then 1 when 'MEDIUM' then 2 else 3 end) as rn
   from books
) t
where rn = 1;
```

The above is standard ANSI SQL, but in Postgres using the (proprietary) `distinct on` is usually much faster:

```
select distinct on (author_id) book_id, author_id, mark, year, 
from books
order by author_id, 
         case mark when 'GREAT' then 1 when 'MEDIUM' then 2 else 3 end
```

Comment: Would you need to partition by `author_id` AND `book_id`?

Comment: @matt: Noam wants the best book per author. If you partition by author **and** book_id you get the best mark for each book for each author. If e.g. there are two books for an author then partitioning by author and book would return both books, not just one.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, it seems like both your solutions worked great when I used Postgres, but when I tried to compose a test for it (using in memory H2) I got this exception for the 'distinct on' solution: `org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Syntax error in SQL statement ... expected "*, NOT, EXISTS, INTERSECTS, SELECT, FROM";`
And this one for the 'partition' solution: `org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Syntax error in SQL statement ... expected ")";`

Comment: Just saw here - http://www.h2database.com/html/roadmap.html - that currently there is no support in window functions in H2... so I need another solution since all my tests uses H2 in memory.

Comment: @Noam: you asked for an ANSI SQL solution. You never mentioned you need this for H2. This is another good example why it's a bad idea to use a different DBMS for testing and production. Check out answers for MySQL with the tag [tag:greatest-n-per-group]. As MySQL doesn't support [modern SQL](http://modern-sql.com/slides) either you'll probably get some answers there. But be prepared that any other solution will be a lot slower with real world data (especially slower then the `distinct on()`)

Comment: Since this solution is true for Postgres - I will accept it.