# Criteria api support for distinct on (Postgres)

Tags: java, mysql, postgresql, criteria, criteria-api

Following my [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37697427/sql-distinct-multiple-columns), is there a way I could write the following query in criteria api?

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (book_id, author_id) book_id, author_id, mark, year 
FROM BOOKS
```

As I understand, the 'distinct on' phrase is only supported by Postgres (which is the database I'm using) and it seems to be just what I'm looking for.
I couldn't use this query directly since my tests uses H2 in memory (converting them to use Postgres is probably a big issue right now).